# Gravity trajectory with already known destination

Tags: libgdx, 2d

I have been spending several days trying to solve this problem and I am about to go mad. Your help would be very much appreciated.

I am using a 2D stage in libgdx. I want to move actors (or sprite) to this stage with a "gravity" display effect: for example for actor1, his initial coordinates are (0, 0), destination coordinates would be (100, 50), and I want to move this actor to this destination with a gravity trajectory effect. Then I want to use the same gravity for actor2 moving from (0, 0) to (25, 75), then actor3 from (0, 0) to (200, 75) etc.

I managed to apply a gravity trajectory to any actor based on this well known loop:

```
setX(getX() + velocity.x);
setY(getY() + velocity.y);
velocity.y += getGravity().y * delta;
```

So tweaking the gravity value would modify the trajectory. It works fine.
Now, as I said earlier I want to give every actors a unique trajectory given their predetermined destination.

So I have tried to find a formula to determine the x and y for each actor at every frame of their trajectory
I am using the following static parameters:

gravity.y : same for all actors
delay : the amount of frames during which each actor moves between his initial coordinates and his destination coordinates. Same value for all actors too

First I calculate the velocity with this SUPER UGLY formula that I am absolutely not proud of:

```
velocity = new Vector2 ( (destinationx - b.getX() )/time,  initdisty/time + ( Math.sqrt(delta*1000)*time / ( 500/Math.abs(gravity) ) ));
```

where delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

Then I apply this velocity each frame to calculate the x and y of each actor:

```
public void act(float delta){
for (int i=0; i<delay; i++) {
setX(getX() + velocity.x);
setY(getY() + velocity.y);
velocity.y += gravity.y * delta;
}
}
```

It KIND OF work, but of course, this can not be a long term solid solution. Calculating the x and y for each frame for each actor (there can be 5-6 actors moving at the same time) doesn't look good at all.
The main problem is that the trajectories are good on computer with consistent 60FPS, they are okay on a tablet, but on a phone with limited memory and 30 < fps < 60, the trajectories become terribly wrong.

After reading several blog posts, it seems like I could avoid the multi device memory fps problems by removing the delta parameter from my formulas, but I haven't found how. And it still doesn't give me a strong long term solution to calculate the trajectory with predetermined destination coordinates.

Thanks for reading and for your time, please let me know if this is unclear I'll do my best to explain better.

Comment: Just to make sure: you have a certain object with a known starting position, and you want to calculate which initial velocity to give it so that the object is at another known location after a known period of time? All this while the object is under the effect of gravity?

Comment: @sashoalm: ok thanks, I removed the tag

Comment: @goncalopp: yes indeed, this is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause of the problem

Maintaining both position and velocity leads to discretization of the system resulting in quantization error. So you will experience inconsistent behavior by your current method when fps fluctuates.

---

### Solution

All you need is to reduce your number of state variables to only two i.e. don't store current velocity. It is causing the errors in final position.

In stead use parametric form of the trajectory.

> v = u + at

and

> s = ut + ½at²

---

### Implementation

Suppose you want to go from (sourceX, sourceY) to (targetX, targetY) in time 'totalTime'.

- Calculate initial velocity.

  ```
  Vector2 initialVelocity = new Vector2((targetX - sourceX) / totalTime,
              (targetY - sourceY) / totalTime - gravity * totalTime / 2);
  float currentTime = 0;
  ```
- In each iteration, calculate position directly and keep track of currentTime.

  ```
  public void act(float delta){
      if (currentTime < totalTime) {
          currentTime += delta;

          setX((initialVelocity.x + gravity.x * currentTime / 2) * currentTime);
          setY((initialVelocity.y + gravity.y * currentTime / 2) * currentTime);
      } else {
          setX(targetX);
          setY(targetY);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for yout great answer. In your scenario, what should be gravity.x ? I thought it should be 0?

Comment: Glad to know it helped. In most cases, gravity.x would be 0 and gravity.y would be negative.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it to work, thanks!
However I am still having problems in case of low framerate (30 fps) like before. any idea how I could fix this ?
At 60fps, no problem

Comment: Hello again, maybe you haven't read my last edit of my last comment (my bad, i was editing my comment while you were answering its first part). Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Are your positions incorrect or are you experiencing stuttering?

Comment: Both I think: occasional suttering cause some actors to end up on a destination slighlty different than the good one, but it looks very ugly on the screen. I have added a dirty fix, where I manually set x and y to the destination coordinates when there is only 3% left of the totalframes. But this is a dirty solution!

Comment: I don't think it changes much this particular problem. I think the cause is rather that delta keeps onchanging. Overriding delta with a static value, I get good results on multi device I think. anyway, thank you for your great answer and your time, you have helped me a lot. Have a nice day